# model.predict() function always returns 1 for binary image classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I was working on a binary image classification deep learning model using transfer learning in Google colab.

```
!wget https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5 -O /tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
local_weights_file = '/tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (300, 300, 3), 
                                include_top = False, 
                                weights = None)
pre_trained_model.load_weights(local_weights_file)
for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7')
last_output = last_layer.output
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(pre_trained_model.input, x)
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
      train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1/255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode="nearest")
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      train_dir,  
      target_size=(300, 300),  
      batch_size=100,
      class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      validation_dir,  
      target_size=(300, 300),  
      batch_size=100,
      class_mode='binary')
history = model.fit(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=20,
      epochs=30,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=10,
      callbacks=[callbacks])

 import numpy as np
 from google.colab import files
 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

 uploaded=files.upload()
 for fn in uploaded.keys():
   path='/content/' + fn
   img=image.load_img(path, target_size=(300, 300))
   x=image.img_to_array(img)
   x=np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
   images = np.vstack([x])
   classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
   print(classes)
```

Even though after training the model and obtaining a quite good accuracy on training and validation data, the model is always predicting 1 for any new image. I have tried changing the batch size, epochs, learning rate, etc. But, no luck.

Can anyone explain what's the problem here?

Comment: Are you rescaling your new images? From what I can see, you scaled your training and validation data, but I am not sure that you did the same for your new images.

Comment: @RichardX Rescaled and it worked! Thank you. Although I don't understand why this model worked without rescaling on pycharm and not on google colab